Programmably imitate drag in PathView
I need to switch elements in PathView, but with coordinates, like user would do with mouse. incrementCurrentIndex is not an option, because I need to drag quarter of an element and half of an element. Path does not contains something of use either. Is it possible to do something like that with PathView?

If all you need is half-step or quarter-steps and everything else was okay, couldn't you just increase the size of your model by 2x or 4x with fillers?

Actually, there is a real (double) offset property, which is responsible for progress and I change it fractionally. There will be a bit of calculations, bit I think this is what I need.
